# Sencha Architect: Sencha Touch Chart components do not display in Android device

Tags: android, extjs, charts, touch

I'm new in Sencha Touch and I use Sencha Architect to build an Android App to display charts.I followed tutorial, the App runs well on web browser and it also runs on Android device, only chart components do not display on Android device...Does anyone know what is wrong? Other UIs display well, only charts don't...
P.S.: I use trial version of Sencha Architect.

Well after a week it works by using Phonegap to package it..Although Sencha claims it has native packager, it doesn't work on Sencha Chart components.

Comment: You should post that as answer to your question instead of editing your question and placing the answer in it to make it obvious that there is an answer at first glance. Otherwise, someone may close tab/browser if they don't see an answer selected.